# New members reported as having one badge seem to have none

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

I have encountered this issue twice today; once could be a glitch, twice is ... ?

The second case concerns the poster of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42423/what-type-of-bicycle-do-i-need-for-euro-trip-throughout-countries

At the time of posting this question, the relevant part of the question page looks like:

[image]

It show the user has one bronze badge.

When I visited the user's profile, it showed

[image]

I generally use this information to write my welcome message for new members; if they have not visited the tour page then I like to suggest that they do.

**Edit**

@Glorfindel suggested that it may be due to caching.

I don't think that can be the case. At least not at my end. I had never opened that page before. When writing this post, I left that page open. After asking Firefox to refresh it, it now shows the user has the editor badge.

The key evidence, I think, is the screen shot that shows "**Badges** (1)" and then show no badges.

Comment: it does say ***rare badges***, chances are the badge they do have isn't a rare one

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com - I *do* see a bronze badge on the user's profile.

Comment: @Memor-X Yes, it shows the rarest badges if there are too many to easily fit on the page :-)

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, so do I, *now*. I have not done anything AFAIK to effect caching, and I have not seen this occur before. I'm [bicycles.se] [top first post reviewer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats) and have been working the same way for ages: if the member seems to have badges I go and check them. If they don't have the [informed badge](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/badges/86/informed)  I suggest they take the tour. So while it may be a caching issue, I strongly doubt it.

Comment: @andy256 i always assumed it just showed the rarest and common badges like Autobiographer and Tutor wouldn't show unless you went to their activity.

Comment: @Memor-X The users [profile](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/29178/tom) now shows the editor badge; not really rare, but the only one he's got.

Comment: I also believe this is some sort of caching, but in the very least, the count should be synchronized with that caching and show 0.

Comment: The caching does not occur on *your* system, but on ours. The information that is used to create the page is generally cached server-side and the only thing anyone can do to get it to update is wait.

Comment: @animuson My take on *the only thing anyone can do to get it to update is wait* means *we goofed the design and we're not going to fix it*. The UI is inconsistent, meaning *wrong*. An attempt to access data that's cached should still get the correct data!  How long does one have to wait? How can your content suppliers (us) know that what we're looking at is correct, in order to supply correct content? It seems to have worsened lately, why is that?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug due to (server side) caching indeed. There have been multiple posts related to 'badges that have appeared and disappeared somehow'.

There are some metrics that are updated once you earn a badge (like the badge count), but the full statistics are calculated once in a while. That might cause some delay before it is visible to you and others.

One other case of this issue that got deleted by a moderator, but which demonstrates the exact same issue can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259016/245360).

Comment: That link says *Page Not Found

This question was removed from Meta Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation ...*

Comment: That is because you don't have sufficient reputation to see deleted questions. Only if you have 10K+ reputation you can.

Comment: I must have a short attention span. The first half of the last sentence in your answer said it was deleted.

Comment: The comment from animuson♦ above shows that you're correct. Shocking to see they think it's ok to present inconsistent data. I'm waiting and hoping for a better SE response.